# Read the value of a string in the dll that is created dynamicly

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

I am trying to create a DLL file in runtime ,as a matter of fact i need to save an encoded data to `DLL` .My code is like this :

```
      class DllFile
    {
        public static void CreateDllFile(string source)
        {
            source = @"using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LicensecodeDll
{
    class Check
    {
        public string returnValue()
        {
            return " + source + ";" + "}}}";



            var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            var options = new CompilerParameters
            {
                OutputAssembly = "test.dll"
            };

            var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, new[] { source });

        }

    }
}
```

every thing works fine and my ddl is created ,but i need to read the value that is saved on the dll file ,i mean i need the `returnValue`.how can i do that?

Best regards.Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Load the assembly and use reflection?

Comment: WOW how can i do that?!!!!!!

Comment: [load assembly using reflection c#](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=load%20assembly%20using%20reflection%20c%23)

Comment: Reflection is where you can ask about objects, such as getting properties and methods. The only way to call stuff where you don't have a reference to a built assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the assembly dynamically and use reflection to call that method. The code should be like this.

```
    Assembly a = Assembly.Load("test.dll");        
    Type myType = a.GetType("LicensecodeDll.Check");        
    MethodInfo myMethod = myType.GetMethod("returnValue");        
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);       
    myMethod.Invoke(obj, null);
```

More detail is on MSDN: How to: [Load Assemblies into an Application Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25y1ya39(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you ,but how can i access the returned value ?

Comment: return myMethod.Invoke(obj, null);?